# extracting 'blob' python serialized tuple data in php

Tags: python, php, serialization, tuples, blob

I'm trying to utilize a database from another program in a php based website tool, and apparently the original was built in python and puts some of it's data into a python tuple and serializes it to store it as a blob in the sql table.

I'm not a python programmer so I'm not sure how to even see what is in this blob, but I do know that some of the 'type' indicators for the data field are stored in there and I want to extract them and anything else useful.

Is there any way to 'unserialize' a python tuple in php?

Comment: Can you tell if the blob content is string-based or just pure binary?

Comment: I found a cludgy solution. The blob turned out to be a pickled tuple. I use an exec to python -c to decode it

Answer (score 0):

The blob data turned out to be a pickled tuple (part of the reason I despise python - both data types that only python can read! Python programmers: 'standardized conventions? Who needs standardized conventions?!?!')

I came up with a cludgy way to 'unpickle' the data and json serialize it using a command line. To get the binary blob data into the command line, I base64 encode it. It's janky but it works for what I need:

```
/**
 * use a python exec call to 'unpickle' the blob_data
 *   to get the binary blob into a command line argument, base64 encode it
 *   to get the data back out of python, json serialize it
 * @param string $blob binary blob data
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function unpickle($blob) {
    $cmd = sprintf("import pickle; import base64; import json; print(json.dumps(pickle.loads(base64.b64decode('%s'))))", base64_encode($blob));
    $pcmd = sprintf("python -c \"%s\"", $cmd);
    $result = exec($pcmd);
    $resdec = json_decode($result);
    return $resdec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little more playing on this concept, I gave myself a few more alternatives. First is, I took the command line version in the previous answer and made it into a little more functional python script:

**unpickle.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pickle
import json
import sys
import base64
import select

def isBase64(s):
    try:
        return s == base64.b64encode(base64.b64decode(s)).decode('ascii')
    except Exception:
        return False

bblob = None
if (len(sys.argv) > 1) and isBase64(sys.argv[1]):
    bblob = base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1])
elif select.select([sys.stdin, ], [], [], 0.0)[0]:
    try:
        with open(0, 'rb') as f:
            bblob = f.read()
    except Exception as e:
        err_unknown(e)

if bblob != None:
    unpik = pickle.loads(bblob)
    jsout = json.dumps(unpik)
    print(jsout)
```

This script allows you to either specify the blob data from the pickled tuple 'byte' as a base64 encoded string on the command line, or you can pipe raw blob data into the script. Both variations will output json if the data is valid and formatted properly. (null if not)

You can convert this to a self-contained binary to plop on systems without python using pyinstaller -F if need be.  To play with it in the event I am running it on systems with the pyinstaller binary vs one with the python script vs one with just python, I created the following static methods in my laravel model. (I'll eventually move it into a service module)

```
/**
 * call either a pyinstaller binary or python script with raw blob data to be unpickled
 *
 * @param string $b  binary data of blob
 * @return false|mixed
 */
public static function unpickle($b)
{
    $cmd = base_path(env('UNPICKLE_BINARY', 'bin/unpickle'));
    if(!(is_file($cmd) && is_executable($cmd))) { // make sure unpickle cmd exists

        // check for UNPICKLE_BINARY with .py after and python binary
        $pyExe = env('PYTHON_EXE', '/usr/bin/python');
        if (is_file($cmd.".py") && (is_file($pyExe) && is_executable($pyExe))) {
            $cmd = sprintf("%s %s.py", $pyExe, $cmd);
        } else
            return static::unpyckle($b); // try direct python call
    }

    $descriptorspec = [
        ["pipe", "r"],
        ["pipe", "w"],
        ["pipe", "w"]
    ];

    $cwd = dirname($cmd);
    $env = [];

    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

    if (is_resource($process)) {
        fwrite($pipes[0], $b);
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);

        $return_value = proc_close($process);

        if(static::isJson($output))
            return json_decode($output);
        else
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * use a python exec call to 'unpickle' the blob_data
 *   to get the binary blob into a command line argument, base64 encode it
 *   to get the data back out of python, json serialize it
 * @param string $blob binary blob data
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function unpyckle($blob) {
    $pyExe = env('PYTHON_EXE', '/usr/bin/python');
    if (!(is_file($pyExe) && is_executable($pyExe)))
        throw new Exception('python executable not found!');

    $bblob = base64_encode($blob);
    $cmd = sprintf("import pickle; import base64; import json; print(json.dumps(pickle.loads(base64.b64decode('%s'))))", $bblob);

    $pcmd = sprintf("%s -c \"%s\"", $pyExe, $cmd);
    $result = exec($pcmd);
    $resdec = json_decode($result);
    return $resdec;
}

/**
 * try to detect if a string is a json string
 *
 * @param $str
 * @return bool
 */
public static function isJson($str) {
    if(is_string($str) && !empty($str)) {
        json_decode($str);
        return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
    }
    return false;
}
```

example .env values:

```
UNPICKLE_BINARY=bin/unpickle
PYTHON_EXE=/usr/bin/python3
```

basically showing three different ways to call python to do essentially the same thing...